# Web Farm Framework + PLINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing

I have a question about web farm framework and PLINQ.

As we know, we can use AsParallel extension in .NET 4.0 Framework.

For example

```
    var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000);


// Opt-in to PLINQ with AsParallel
var evenNums = from num in source.AsParallel()
               where Compute(num) > 0
               select num;
```

I know web farm framework will do the auto load balancing for me.

Assume I have 3 servers:

Sever A: 8 cores
Sever B: 4 cores
Sever C: 4 cores

The question is how many total CPU cores I receive? Is it 8+4+4=16 cores?

I am asking because I am wondering how many CPU cores are available to the parallel computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel LINQ is uses the cores available **only on the machine it is executing**. I believe there are some 3rd party products (Microsoft Research has [DryadLINQ](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/dryadlinq/)) which can extend it to a cluster, however, out of the box this is not possible.

Additionally, *cores available* and *threads used* are two separate things (to nitpick even more, unmanaged and managed threads are also two separate things).

To answer your question, regardless of which server the code executes on, PLINQ may use 1 or more threads (up to a limit provided by the scheduler being used). It all depends on the workload.

Comment: In addition, the web farm framework will not do anything in this case?

Comment: The web farm will mean you're balanced overall, because other queries will be dealt with. PLINQ will just mean that **maybe** a given request to a given webserver will benefit.

Comment: @user361022: as Jon said the Web Farm framework is more intended to balance HTTP requests rather than the workload *per server*. I'm not 100% certain as to its features, but it may redirect a request away from a machine which is CPU busy. This feature could help if Server A and C are saturated running PLINQ while B is free.

Comment: Cool, I think I understand now. PLINQ divides query into smaller chunks. Web farm framework divides the HTTP request.